# How to use Monitor class and object lock to prevent a method from executing if previously lock had been acquired

Tags: c#, .net

I have a timer whose interval is 60 secs and in its timer_elapsed eventhandler, I'm executing a method. I just want to skip the next call to method if current call is still running, provided that time has elapsed and next call to method is ready. How can I do it with Monitor and object lock?.
Here's snippet of my code

```
private static object lock = new object();
private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Monitor.Enter(lock);
    try
    {
      SomeMethod();
    }
    finally
    {
      Monitor.Exit(lock);
    }
}
```

I just want to skip the whole call to method if previous call is still in progress.

Comment: That is not the correct workaround for forgetting to set the timer's AutoReset property to false.  You'll make it a lot worse with Monitor or lock, you'll just pile up threads that can't complete, badly clogging the threadpool.  That it is true by default is very, very evil.  But System.Timers.Timer is evil all around.  Simply call Start() again at the end of the method, you get to choose if you want to change the Interval so it is better paced.  Watch out for the other evil thing it does, it swallows any exception and that will bypass your Start() call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.monitor.tryenter?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Monitor_TryEnter_System_Object_). This method tries to acquire lock and returns the result of this operation. It also has some useful overloads, for example it can try to acquire lock with specified timeout.

```
private static object lock = new object();
private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    bool haveLock = false;

    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(lock, ref haveLock);
        if (haveLock)
        {
            SomeMethod(); 
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (haveLock)
        {
            Monitor.Exit(lock);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: minor note: there are *apparently* some edge cases around thread exits that make it desirable to prefer the `bool haveLock = false; Monitor.TryEnter(lock, ref haveLock); if (!haveLock) return;` approach *inside* the `try`/`finally`, so that there is no period when you can have the lock *and* not already have the (admittedly, also limited) guarantee of `finally`

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you! It does indeed sound correct to have everything within `try..finally`. I have updated the answer, let me know if something is wrong :)

Comment: looks great to me :)

Comment: Sorry, tried your way. But whenever my current call is getting executed and next call comes to method, `haveLock` returns true.Control goes inside `SomeMethod`. Even when I'm debugging the current code. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I use `Monitor.Enter(lock)`, next call waits untill I finish current call and then exceutes immidiately. Is there a way around to skip that call?

Comment: @SamratMatte you could try using the overload that takes a timeout, and pass 0 ?\